# naming objects using for loop

Tags: for-loop, naming

is there a way to name a series of objects like so:

```
for (i=0; i<numberOfObjectsDesired; i++;) {
    Object ("thisone"+i);
    thisone+i = new Object();
}
```

such that
 thisone0, thisone1, thisone2, thisone3, ... etc are all unique instances of Objects

Comment: What language are you trying to do this in?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, it's called an **array**:

```
var thisone = new object[numberOfObjectsDesired];

for (i=0; i<numberOfObjectsDesired; i++;) {
    Object ("thisone"+i);
    thisone[i] = new Object();
}
```

Just note that you have to refer to your instances as `thisone[0]`, `thisone[1]`, etc. instead of `thisone0`, `thisone1`, ...

Comment: Snarky but accurate.  I like it!